# Pyspark (Pandas on Spark) OOM Error with Series.apply()

Tags: pyspark, out-of-memory, pyspark-pandas

I'm running some transformations on a relatively small dataset (2gb). I'm using a spark pool with 2 executors with 8 cores that have 56gb memory each, which should be overkill. The dataset is being partitioned in 20 pieces, which I think makes sense. However, I am consistently getting OOM errors (`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`) when applying functions to the dataframe or series from the dataframe. For example,

```
def get_date(x):
    try:
        std_date = dparser.parse(x, fuzzy=True)
        return std_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    except Exception as e:
        return None

df[std_date_colname] = df['og_date'].apply(get_date)
```

Returns an error.

As I have been playing around with different configurations, some runs are calling `DataFrame.to_pandas()`, which understandably causes an OOM error, but I don't understand why `to_pandas()` is being called in the first place.

I have not been able to find any documentation for why `DataFrame.apply()` or `Series.apply()` would cause spillage like this. Because some runs seem to be shuffling, I have tried increasing `spark.executor.memoryOverheadFactor` to allow more room for shuffle, but it has not helped.

Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Thank you!